# Pycharm tkinter displays gui and a green border appears around the window but nothing else works

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I am new to Python and using pycharm. Everything I tried worked until about an hour ago. The application is running but a green border appears around the gui (tkinter) and no code works. I run a simple print string but nothing happens. I have added buttons and frames and the application runs but the buttons and frames don't appear. All previous project run just fine but all new projects I create does the above mentioned. I am not sure what I did, any ideas?

Below are screenshots. The first two show the issue and the bottom shows an exercise I did before that runs just fine.

[image]

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

print ("Ready")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it. Nothing to do with python settings or anything python or pycharm related. It was other software namely Comodo Firewall. There is an issue that occurs where the Firewall notifications popup and close instantly. This happened and it placed the application in a sandbox that is why it didn't run any code. Comodo has no solution other than uninstalling and reinstalling the firewall which is a pain. Everything working now...